# Error code 400 (Bad request) while trying to send message through Telegram API

Tags: python, chatbot, telegram-bot

I am trying to make a bitcoin Telegram Bot, that will send current bitcoin rate.

I am stuck with the Telegram API part of my code, where I need to send my message.

```
 @bot.message_handler(commands=['bit']) 
 def bit(message):
    link = 'https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker'
    response = requests.get(link).text
    text = json.loads(response)
    bot.send_message('Продажа ',text["RUB"]["sell"],'рублей','\nПокупка ',text["RUB"]["buy"],'рублей')
```

The needed libraries such as json, requests, telebot are all properly installed.

Other commands like `/start` or just answering on usual messages works fine, but this is the error I get when trying to send the bitcoin rate:

```
Error text: ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: unsupported parse_mode"
```

[Image representation of code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foAOq.png)

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. See the meta post [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: And reduce the code to an [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are sticking to the signature for `send_message()` detailed in your api [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html)?

It looks like you are giving several arguments for your text parameter, try to wrap it up in a statement, like:

```
text = json.loads(response)
messageText = 'Продажа '+text["RUB"]["sell"]+'рублей'+'\nПокупка '+text["RUB"]["buy"]+'рублей'
```

Then invoke the `send_message()` method, providing the following three **non-optional** parameters:

1. `chat_id`
2. `text`
3. `parse_mode`

So that:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['bit']) 
def bit(message):
    link = 'https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker'
    response = requests.get(link).text
    text = json.loads(response)
    chatId = '@channelusername'
    messageText = 'Продажа '+text["RUB"]["sell"]+'рублей'+'\nПокупка '+text["RUB"]["buy"]+'рублей'
    bot.send_message(chatId, messageText, parse_mode=HTML)
```

Of course, don't forget to edit your `chatId`, which has to be "The unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target channel (in the format @channelusername)".